# "Recommend someone to represent..." vs. "recommend someone represent..."

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Looking at the sentence below I have a feeling it is wrong, though I can't explain why:

> I highly recommend Dave to represent you in Korea with your software.

I have thus rephrased it to the following:

> I highly recommend Dave represent you in Korea with your software.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both are correct, but mean slightly different things.

> I highly recommend Dave —> to represent you in Korea with your software.

I would use this in a context where it is established that you need someone to represent you, and it is just a matter of figuring out who.  So, this sentence is saying that it is Dave who I recommend.

> I highly recommend (that) —> Dave represent you in Korea with your software.

This one could be used in the context I described above, but also when there are many possible courses of action — it may not be established that you should have someone represent you.  So, this sentence is saying "Dave representing you" is what I recommend.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the first example implies
there was a choice between Dave and someone else, and Dave is the “answer”.

The second example feels a bit more like the idea of representation itself (by Dave, or anyone) is a new suggestion.

For what it’s worth, for me the confusion is this: is Dave representing You or the software? The placement of “Korea” disrupts the flow of the sentence and makes it confusing.

For example:

I highly recommend that Dave represent you and the software in Korea.

Or

Dave would do a great job presenting your software in Korea.

OR

Dave would do a great job presenting the software in Korea.

OR

I highly recommend Dave for your representative in Korea. He’d do a great job presenting the software.

Comment: The first two sentences, the core of the answer, surely just paraphrase (or very nearly for the sentence with the content clause) the accepted answer's analysis.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/427203)